# PyQT, QDialog в новом потоке

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt, qthread, qdialog

`QWidget` работает в главном потоке.

Пытаюсь реализовать автоматическое обновление базы программы. 
В новом потоке **каждые шесть часов** на сервер отправляется запрос на наличие новой базы, которую необходимо скачать. 
Если обновление есть, то пользователю выводится `QDialog` с предложением обновить базу (две кнопки: "обновить" и "игнорировать").

Т.к. поток, работающий с `QDialog` не является главным потоком, в котором работает `QWidget`, то `QDialog` работает не стабильно, через раз вылетает.

Как можно решить эту проблему и каким образом реализуются подобные системы?
Пока копаю в сторону вызова метода главного потока из дочернего.

Пример кода. В отдельном потоке будет осуществляться проверка на наличие обновлений, сообщение пользователю и после одобрения обновление будет скачиваться с сервера.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QSystemTrayIcon, \
     QStyle, QAction, qApp, QMenu, QDialog, QLabel, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout 
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QEvent, QSize, QRect, QPoint 
import threading 
import sys


class ScreenArea(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        super().__init__()
        w = QWidget()
        w.resize(250, 150)
        w.move(300, 300)
        w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
        w.show()
        threading.Thread(target=self.dial, daemon=True, args=("From QDialog",)).start()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def dial(self, message):
        d = QDialog()
        b1 = QPushButton("ok", d)
        b1.move(50, 50)
        d.setWindowTitle(message)
        d.setWindowModality(Qt.ApplicationModal)
        d.exec_()

w = ScreenArea()
```

Comment: Вы можете опубликовать минимальный пример демонстрирующий проблему?

Comment: Добавил. QDialog работает не стабильно. Например при клике на кнопку может исчезнуть кнопка, а может произойти вылет.

Comment: Qt, как и подавляющее большинство GUI-библиотек, не является потокобезопасным. Все взаимодействия с графическими компонентами, к которым относится и QDialog, должны выполняться только из главного потока. Поток проверяющий обновления должен отправлять сигнал главному потоку, а главный поток должен реагировать на этот сигнал открытием диалогового окна.

Comment: Тогда получается главный поток должен ждать сигнал от проверяющего обновления. В этот момент программа будет подвисать.

Comment: @chessinvin с чего бы? Сигналы асинхронны по своей природе. Программа же не подвисает, когда ждёт клика по кнопке.

Answer (score 3):

Приведу пример создания в отдельном потоке проверки обновлений, с уведомлением о доступности.

Когда из потока придет сигнал с сообщением о новой версии, главный поток это покажет и позволит обработать.

[Код:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/1a63011d314e490b785de86733b4aeab81105efb/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyqt__UpdaterMessageExample__QThread.py#L10)

```
from PyQt5.Qt import (
    QThread, pyqtSignal, QMessageBox, QApplication, QWidget, QLabel,
    QPlainTextEdit, QVBoxLayout
)


class AboutUpdateThread(QThread):
    about_update = pyqtSignal(str)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # Делаем какие-то действия и проверки, и вызываем сигнал about_update,
            # чтобы сообщить о новой версии
            # ...
            # if ...:

            self.about_update.emit('Доступна новая версия 2.1.1')

            # 6 hours
            QThread.sleep(6 * 60 * 60)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.log = QPlainTextEdit()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QLabel('Log:'))
        layout.addWidget(self.log)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.thread = AboutUpdateThread(self)
        self.thread.about_update.connect(self.on_about_update)
        self.thread.start()

    def add_log(self, text):
        self.log.appendPlainText(text)

    def on_about_update(self, text):
        self.add_log("Пришло обновление '{}'".format(text))
        
        mb = QMessageBox()
        mb.setWindowTitle("Доступно обновление")
        mb.setText("Сейчас доступно обновление")
        mb.setDetailedText(text)
        button_ok = mb.addButton("Обновить", QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
        button_cancel = mb.addButton("Отклонить", QMessageBox.RejectRole)
        
        mb.exec()
        
        if mb.clickedButton() == button_cancel:
            self.add_log('Пользователь отказался от обновления...')
            return
        
        self.add_log('Выполняю обновление...')

        # ...
        # Обновляемся
        # ...

        self.add_log('Обновление поставлено успешно...')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = Window()
    mw.resize(400, 400)
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Мне думается, что ваша идея, может выглядеть так:

```
import sys
import threading
from random          import randrange
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QThread, QTimer, pyqtSignal, Qt, QTime
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QDialog, 
                            QLabel, QLCDNumber, QPlainTextEdit, QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QFont

class WorkerThread(QThread):

    my_signal = pyqtSignal(str, int, name='my_signal')
    flag = 0

    def run(self):
        def work():
            # отправляется запрос на проверку наличия чего-то
            th = threading.Thread(target=self.dial, daemon=True, args=("From QDialog",)).start()
            QThread.sleep(5)
            self.my_signal.emit("Результат отправляем в главный поток", self.flag)

        self.my_signal.emit("Запускаем 6-ти часовой таймер.", self.flag)
        timer = QTimer()
        timer.timeout.connect(work)
        timer.start(6000)           # предположим, что 1 сек. = 1 час
        self.exec_()

    def dial(self, arg):
        """ Симулятор работы сервера, проверка на наличие обновлений """
        self.flag = randrange(0, 2) # 0 - нет обновлений, 1 - есть обноовления
        QThread.sleep(3000)         # Пусть запрос выполняется некоторое время


class MyGui(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUi()

        self.worker = WorkerThread(self)
        self.worker.my_signal.connect(self.mySignalHandler)
        self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("Начало работы.")
        self.worker.start()

    def initUi(self):
        self.setGeometry(400, 100, 600, 300)

        self.lcdTime = QLCDNumber()
        self.lcdTime.setMinimumHeight(70)
        self.lcdTime.setSegmentStyle(QLCDNumber.Filled)   
        self.lcdTime.setDigitCount(8)  
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        self.timer.start(1000)

        self.plainTextEdit = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.plainTextEdit.setFont(QFont('Arial', 11))

        layoutV = QVBoxLayout()
        layoutV.addWidget(self.lcdTime)
        layoutV.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit)
        self.setLayout(layoutV)

    def showTime(self):
        time = QTime.currentTime()
        text = time.toString("hh:mm:ss")           
        if ((time.second() % 2) == 0):
            text = text[0:2] + ' ' + text[3:5] + ' ' + text[6:]
        self.lcdTime.display(text)

    def mySignalHandler(self, text, val):
        self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("Что-то пришло из потока: text={}, val={}"
                                      "".format(text, val))
        if val:
            self.d  = QDialog()
            lbl = QLabel("Есть какие-то обновления. \nЧто будем делать?", self.d)
            lbl.move(50, 50)
            b1 = QPushButton("Обновить", self.d)
            b1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.myDialog("Обновить"))
            b1.move(50, 150)
            b2 = QPushButton("Игнорировать", self.d)
            b2.move(150, 150)
            b2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.myDialog("Игнорировать"))
            self.d.setWindowTitle(text)
            self.d.setWindowModality(Qt.ApplicationModal)
            self.d.exec_()

    def myDialog(self, text):
        if text == "Обновить":
            self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("Нажата кнопка `Обновить`. "
                                          "<b style='color:red;'>Надо что-то делать.</b>")
        else:
            self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("Нажата кнопка `Игнорировать`. Нечего делать.")
        self.d.reject()


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = MyGui()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `timer = QTimer()` не нужен. В `run` можно просто создать бесконечный цикл (`while (true) {`) и в нем делать все работу, sleep тоже там вызывать

Comment: @gil9red мне бесконечные циклы не очень нравятся :), а `timer = QTimer()` делает свою работу каждые 6 часов.

Comment: Кст, а как вам решение через `QMessageBox`?

Comment: @gil9red мне нравится. Пускай теперь chessinvin думает, что ему делать :)